# Why are islower() and friends required to handle EOF?

Tags: c, glibc, c-standard-library

Why are `islower()` and friends required to handle `EOF`, whereas `putchar()` and friends don't have to?

Why isn't `islower()` treating `int` as `unsigned char`, as it is the case in `putchar()`? This would make total sense, because we have to check for `EOF` first anyway. See also [Why the argument type of `putchar()`, `fputc()`, and `putc()` is not `char`?](/q/40712493/)

Comment: `unsigned char` is a thing of ancient times. With it's length of 8 bit, is not capable of working with non-western langauges, with accented letters, emojis etc.

Comment: @Codo: and `islower()` does, in the standard library?

Comment: @RadLexus: I'm not really sure. I think it does if the locale is set correctly.

Answer (score 4):

> because we have to check for EOF first anyway.

We absolutely don't.

```
int c;
while(isspace(c=fgetc(fp)));
if (c==EOF) ...
```

This is totally legitimate code to skip whitespaces. Checking each character for EOF separately is a waste of time.

The ctype functions are made to handle EOF specifically to enable code like this.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623978/why-do-ctype-functions-take-int-but-want-unsigned-char-eof).

Comment: Looking at [a random implementation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/ctype.h.htm) of `isspace` & friends suggests that `-1` is *explicitly* taken care of: `#define isspace(c)      ((__ctype+1)[(unsigned int)c]&_S)`. Here, `__ctype` is a simple array, but note the rather sneaky `+1`!

Comment: "The ctype functions are made to handle EOF specifically to enable code like this." - where this is written in the standard? This is just your opinion. Things are more rational than that.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The standard rarely mentions rationales for its decisions, you need to go elsewhere to find them. Folk wisdom is one source.

Answer (score 1):

None of character type functions are required to handle `EOF`, other than ignoring it (i.e. returning false). In fact, EOF marker is [not even mentioned in `<ctype.h>` header documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/ctype.h.html).

The most likely reason for character classification function signatures to use `int` in place of `char`, signed or unsigned, is to avoid implementation-defined behavior in loops like this:

```
int c;
while ((c =getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (islower(c)) {
        ...
    } else if (isdigi(c)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This would compile and run with `islower(char)` instead of `islower(int)`, but [the result would be implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25080246/335858), which is not desirable under such basic circumstances. Essentially, `int` in the signature of `getchar` became "contagious," getting into signatures of functions only marginally related to it.

Comment: What would "ignore" mean in this context? The functions are required to accept EOF and return `false` for it.

Comment: means return that EOF is not space

Comment: Also, you have answered a slughtly different question, "why the argulent type of isalpha is int". The actual question is "why isalpha must be defined for EOF". For any other int value which does not fit unsigned char the result is undefined.

Comment: The EOF marker [*is* mentioned in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/islower.html) and the [C language standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4) as well. The ctype functions *are* required to handle EOF without causing undefined behavior, so you're not answering the question.

Comment: @nwellnhof You have no clarity on what's undefined behavior, and how it is different from implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: I think that the "contagious" behavior is not the primary reason. I think the things are more rational. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/40732303/1487773/